# Fastest way to search a HashMap and mark places with the same name?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, search, hashmap

My program has a search function where the user enters the name of a place that gets visible and marked on a map (if the place exists). I'm trying to find the fastest way to search a HashMap for places with the same name, mark them/make them visible and finally add all the marked places to an ArrayList. At the moment, about 2000 closely located places takes about 30 seconds to appear on the map as mentioned, and I've heard that operations such as these are supposed to go much faster. I'm guessing that my for loop is what's slowing things down. Is there a faster way to do this than below?

```
private Map<String, List<Place>> perName = new HashMap<>();

List<Place> sameName = perName.get(name);
                for (Place p : sameName) {
                    p.setVisible(true);
                    p.setMarked(true);
                }
                markedPlace.addAll(sameName);
```

Edit: Here are parts of the Place-class, such as the setMarked()-method (setVisible just shows the graphic components):

```
private boolean isMarked = false;
    private boolean isShown = false;
    private int[] xs = { 0, 20, 40 };
    private int[] ys = { 0, 40, 0 };

    protected Place(String name, Position position, String category) {
        setBounds(position.getX() - 20, position.getY() - 40, 40, 40);
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.category = category;
    }

    protected int[] getXs() {
        return xs;
    }

    protected int[] getYs() {
        return ys;
    }    

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (isShown) {
                show(g);
            }
            if (isMarked) {
                mark(g);
            }
        }

        protected void setShown(boolean b) {
            isShown = b;
            repaint();
        }

        protected boolean isMarked() {
            return isMarked;
        }

        protected void setMarked(boolean b) {
            isMarked = b;
            repaint();
        }

        protected void mark(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, 39, 39);
        }

        protected void show(Graphics g) {
            if (category.equals("Bus")) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (category.equals("Underground")) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else if (category.equals("Train")) {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (category.equals("None")) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            g.fillPolygon(getXs(), getYs(), 3);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the lookup in the hashmap is where the bulk of this time is being spent?  I think rendering so many markers on the map (Google Map?) could definitely take some time.

Comment: If that list just contains 2000 elements and `setVisible()` and `setMarked()` are just simple setters (i.e. no fancy logic inside) the loop should run in just a few milliseconds (on most reasonable hardware even in under 1 ms).

Comment: Btw, handling `Map<String, List<Place>>` can be a pain in the a... . You might consider having a look at Google Guava which has things like multimaps and thus you could use `ListMultimap<String, Place>` and get rid of manually handling the lists. That wouldn't be faster but probably easier to code and read.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes maybe, I added more of the code that's in the for loop

Comment: @Thomas yes that's what I thought too. I now added more of the code in the for loop

Comment: Easy test to try: Clock how long it takes to iterate over the map and just access the 2000 some odd places _without_ doing any graphics stuff.  If that takes a trivially small amount of time, then you'd have a better idea of what the culprit might be.

Comment: One problem could be that each place seems to be an individual component which could introduce quite some overhead. Instead you could try to have a map component which renders the places inside its own `paint()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, try this:

```
markedPlace.addAll(perName.get(name).stream().peek(Place::setVisible).peek(Place::setMarked).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comments appreciated.

Edit: I agree with the others. The performance problem is in my opinion not because of the structure of your loop. More likely it's because of the repaint() call or whatever you are calling in setVisible()